# Type mismatch with generics sum type

Tags: scala

I have a sum trait, that looks like as follow:

```
sealed trait Sum[+A, +B]

final case class Failure[A](value: A) extends Sum[A, Nothing]

final case class Success[B](value: B) extends Sum[Nothing, B]
```

When I try to create a new variable as:

```
val s1: Sum[Int, Nothing] = Success(4)
```

I've got following error:

```
Error:(5, 41) type mismatch;
 found   : Int(4)
 required: Nothing
    val s1: Sum[Int, Nothing] = Success(4)
```

Why?

And why this is working:

```
val s1: Sum[Int, Int] = Success(4)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `B` is the second type parameter, not the first:

```
val s1: Sum[Nothing, Int] = Success(4)
```